# UPDATE MySQL incorrect syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js, put

[image]

I am trying to do a put request on the front end but I am getting a mysql error

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
      method:"GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
        const rowText = "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\"  class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
          $("#movies").append(rowText);
        });

renderMovieList('movies');
  function renderMovieList(){
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $('#movies').empty();
    $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
    const rowText = "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\"  class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal2\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
      $("#movies").append(rowText);
    });
    }
  });
}
  $("#movieAdded").click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let mydata = {
      idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    displayMovie(mydata);

    $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#newForm").toggle();
  });

  $("#updateMovie").on("click", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
      name: $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
      thumnail_path: $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
      description: $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
      year_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
      language_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
    }

    putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);

    $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#updateForm").toggle();
});

function getOneMovie(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist" + id,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
      $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
      $("#updateForm").show();
    }
  });
}

function displayMovie(mydata) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: mydata,
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
      renderMovieList();
}
});
}

function loadButtons() {
              $(".editMovie").click(function (a) {
                  getOneMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });

              $(".deleteMovie").click(function (a) {
                  deleteMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });
          }

loadButtons();
function putMovie(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/updateMovie/2",
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      getOneMovie();
    }
  });
}



function deleteMovie(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/" + id,
    method: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}

}
})

});
```

and also here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Adil@123',
  database: 'movies'

});
mysqlConnection.connect(err=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log('It was not successful \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
  } else {
    console.log('Its a success');
  }
  });
 //  Collecting all the movies from the movielist
  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 // Finding a movie based on the `idmovielist` number
   app.get('/movielist',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err, rows,fields) =>{
    if (!err) {
      res.send(rows);
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });

  // Delting a movie
   app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
  // Inserting a movie
  app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
    //console.log("movielist/addMovie : ",req.body);
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (`idmovielist`,`name`,`thumnail_path`,`description`,`language_released`,`year_released`) VALUES ('"+req.body.idmovielist+"', '"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.thumnail_path+"', '"+req.body.description+"', '"+req.body.year_released+"', '"+req.body.language_released+"')",
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});

app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  const update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET ? WHERE idmovielist = ?",[update], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

// localhost:3000
app.listen(3000,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = app;
```

So as you see in my post method of my app.js I have not hard coded any values for my put method what can I do so that I do not have to go back to my app.js  to change values for my update query plus I want to do the put method on the front end of the UI

Comment: **WARNING**: You're using placeholder values (`?`) in many of your queries but not all of them. You need to be vigilant about doing this every time to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The command getting executed is:

```
update movielist set where idmovielist = ?
```

It's missing the rest of the `set` clause. Try filling that part out in your query:

```
mysqlConnection.query(
    "update movielist set col1 = ?, col2 = ? WHERE idmovielist = ?",
    [req.body.col1, req.body.col2, req.params.id],
    function (err, results) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

It's necessary to specify the columns you want to update.

Comment: app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  const update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = ?, thumnail_path = ?, description = ?, year_released = ?, language_released = ?, WHERE idmovielist = ?",
  [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});   When I do this all my values become null

Comment: @AdilAli interesting, are the update values actually present - perhaps print some logging to determine that.

Comment: I get this errror 'Column \'name\' cannot be null',  and this is my code app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  const update = req.body;
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = ?, thumnail_path = ?, description = ?, year_released = ?, language_released = ? WHERE idmovielist = ?",
  [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

Comment: Right, sounds like `req.body.name` is null or undefined. Is it being set in the request?

Comment: yea I have a variable named update let update = req.body [update.name]

Comment: Perhaps print `update.name` to the console to see if it has a value?

Comment: app.put('/movielist/updateMovie/:id',(req,res) =>{
  let update = req.body;
  console.log(update.name);
  mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET name = ?, thumnail_path = ?, description = ?, year_released = ?, language_released = ? WHERE idmovielist = ?",
  [update.name,update.thumnail_path,update.description,update.year_released,update.language_released,req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}); like this nothing shows up

Comment: So it doesn't look like the body of the request has defined those parameters. They need to be set in the request for the function to read them.

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: If it's a web form add something like `<input type=text name=name />`. If it's being done programmatically set that parameter in the POST or GET request using your HTTP client API.

Comment: Yes, perhaps try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522034/node-js-express-form-post-req-body-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the `assignment_list` operator. From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), the correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

You have the value binding (i.e. the `?`) but no field defined. Try the following:

```
UPDATE movelist SET [column_name_here] WHERE idmovelist = ?
```